# adding new scheduling policy to the kernel

Tags: linux, performance-tuning, linux-kernel

i'm working on a redhat 8 linux and i want to add new policy for scheduling the processes , could you help me with :
1) where to define the new policy
2) how does the process of assigning a policy for a process goes?

detailing function names and structs would be helpful .

Comment: see http://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_setscheduler

Answer (score 1):

You're referring to [Red Hat version 8.0](https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/rh8-errata.html), running a 2.4-series kernel?? That version was end-of-life back in 2003 or 2004. I don't believe the realtime scheduling policies are available in any kernel prior to 2.6.x, based on the link provided in the first comment on the post.

Edit: The kernel in use is actually a 2.6.x kernel. The command needed to make this work is `chrt`. In this case, it will need to be backported or compiled from scratch for the Red Hat 8.0 server. I suspect you'll run into other issues doing so, but for anyone else who stumbles upon this, `chrt` allows this.

From the man page:

```
NAME
       chrt - manipulate real-time attributes of a process

SYNOPSIS
       chrt [options] [prio] [pid | command [arg]...]

DESCRIPTION
       chrt(1)  sets or retrieves the real-time scheduling attributes of an existing PID or runs COMMAND
       with  the  given  attributes.   Both  policy  (one  of  SCHED_OTHER,  SCHED_FIFO,  SCHED_RR,   or
       SCHED_BATCH) and priority can be set and retrieved.
```

A real example:

```
# Set JSINIT processes for e-commerce to FIFO scheduler and realtime priority 75.
for i in `pgrep -f 'JSINIT\ I.*' | xargs`; do chrt -p -f 75 $i; done
```

Comment: yes i know , but it is a custom kernel with the scheduling policies from kernel 2.6.x

Comment: The userspace command you need in order to change application scheduling is `chrt`. You would need to backport it into the RH8.0 system.